# how to set and use partials view paths in node.js + expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, view, ejs

I am having problems in setting partial view paths in nodeJs + expressJs. Below is my directory structure.

Directory Structure

```
packages
--Module1  
----Views
------sample.ejs
--sharedModule
----Views
------partials
--------Module1.ejs
--------partialHTML.ejs      //able to use in index.ejs
------index.ejs  //Used : <% include partials/partialHTML%>
```

**ExpressJS:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'packages/sharedModule/views'));
```

I am able to use `'partialHTML.ejs'` in `index.ejs` file using `<% include partials/partialHTML%>.`.

How can i use `Module1.ejs` files under `Module1/view/sample.ejs` file ?

Comment: Where in the structure does `__dirname` point to?

Comment: @Kof It points to my absolute path. for example. D:/myProject/NodeProject. and this NodeProject contains this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You've set `packages/sharedModule/views` as your views directory, `sample.ejs` is no where under that dir, it's under another path. That's why it's not found.

In Linux you could create a soft link to point the shared views `Module1/views/sharedviews` ==> `../../sharedModule/views`, then set your `Module1` as the root path for views -

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'packages/Module1/views'));
```

So when you look for any view, it's guaranteed to be found, since now your `views` dir has both `Module1` and `sharedModule` views.